# How can I create a simple pure CSS gallery/slideshow for bootstrap landing page?

Tags: html, css, gallery

I’m working on a simple bootstrap landing page. (note that I am not good at coding).

I am trying to create sth like this [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOLfB.jpg).

It's a gallery/ slideshow.

I was trying to follow this tutorial `https://codeconvey.com/pure-css-image-slider/`

(I prefer pure css/html solutions) and change it to suit my needs but didn’t work. The image of the gallery should take 8 columns (left part). On the right I want the arrows and the label-description of each image.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show us your code so we can tell where you are going wrong? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Use Bootstrap Carousel

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can add slider controls as

```
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
```

[Read More Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)

Answer (score 0):

There is what I got using the *standard Bootstrap 4 carousel*, some BS4 *alignment classes*, some *custom CSS*, plus a script that turns inline images (slides) into background images:

```js
var setCarouselImage = function() {
  $('#demo').find('.carousel-item .image-container').each(function() {
    var imgContainer = $(this),
      bkImg = imgContainer.find('img').attr('src');
    if ($(window).width() > 575) {
      imgContainer.css("background-image", 'url("' + bkImg + '")');
    } else {
      imgContainer.css("background-image", 'none');
    }
  });
}

setCarouselImage();
$(window).resize(setCarouselImage);
```

```css
.carousel {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.carousel-control-next,
.carousel-control-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: .9 !important;
  bottom: auto !important;
  width: 4% !important;
  height: 12% !important;
}

.carousel-control-next:hover,
.carousel-control-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
  left: auto !important;
  right: 6% !important;
}

.carousel-item .row {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-item .image-container {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-item img {
  display: none;
}

.carousel-item .text-container {
  display: flex;
}

.carousel-item p {
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .carousel-item .text-container {
    display: block;
  }
  .carousel-item .row {
    height: auto;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .carousel-item img {
    display: block;
  }
  .carousel-item p {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    text-align: justify;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8 image-container p-0">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?random" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-container bg-success">
            <p class="mt-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, consequuntur necessitatibus doloremque tempora deserunt.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8 image-container p-0">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=north" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-container bg-success">
            <p class="mt-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, consequuntur necessitatibus doloremque tempora deserunt repudiandae eveniet?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8 image-container p-0">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/800/?gravity=east" alt="Second slide">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-container bg-success">
            <p class="mt-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore amet aut, eaque nemo totam ex. Ut facilis consequatur voluptates necessitatibus doloremque tempora deserunt.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span></a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```